# calling user role in Netsuite on view cart page

Tags: javascript, netsuite

In Netsuite, the following code works in the header to pull the users role on most of the webstore.

```
    var context=  nlapiGetContext();
   var userRole = context.getRole();
```

But on the viewCart page we get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: nlapiGetContext is not defined" How can I make this code work on the viewCart  page?

We tried using a JSON but are having issues due to single source requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the attribute tags to grab fields on the web store.  In your case you want to use:

`<%=getCurrentAttribute('customer', 'role')%>`

Comment: Turns out that I needed <%=getCurrentAttribute('customer', 'accessrole')%> Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

nlapiGetContext API is only supported in client, user event, scheduled, portlet, and Suitelet scripts which is the reason why you get the error.

How many customer center role do you assign on your customers?

Comment: Between 1 and 5.  Why does it work in the header on most webstore pages, but not the View Cart page.  Is there something special about that page?